# Replace perticular IP (Match exact IP) Address with new IP in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a file which contains many id adress (Both IPV4 and IPV6). I want to use sed command to replace all the occurances of the old IP to new IP. But i am facing a problem ex:

old IPs like below

```
2.2.2.2             -IPV4      
2:2:2.2.2.2         - IPV6: Note ':'
```

In ksh, I am using

```
oldIP=2.2.2.2
newIP=3.3.3.3

sed -i 's/'$oldIP'/'$newIP'/g' filename.
```

But this is replacing both 2.2.2.2 and 2:2:2.2.2.2 because '.' in oldIP variable is used as regular expression.

Can any one tell how to match exact IP of a file in a scipt?

Input file: a.txt - contains oldIP,newIP

```
1.1.1.1,9.9.9.9
0.0.0.0,9.9.9.9
2.2.2.2,9.9.9.9
5:5:5.5.5.5,[9:9:9.9.9.9]
3.3.3.3,9.9.9.9
3:3:3.3.3.3,9:9:9.9.9.9
1:1:3.3.3.3,9:9:9.9.9.9

#!/bin/ksh

ipAddrFile=$1
while read line
do
    OLDIFS=$IFS
    IFS=","
    array=( $line )
    IFS=$OLDIFS

    if [ "${array[1]}" = "" ]; then
        echo "tokenize ip address list fail. Check if proper separator is used."
    fi

    oldIP=${array[0]}
    newIP=${array[1]}

    `sed -i 's/'$oldIP'/'$newIP'/g' temp.xml`
       if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
       echo "Replacing field value failed"
      exit 1
   fi


done < $ipAddrFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all dot needs to be escaped in regex otherwise it matches any character**. So set your variable like this:

```
oldIP="2\.2\.2\.2"
newIP="3.3.3.3"
```

Then you can use this sed:

```
sed -r "s/(^|[^:])$oldIP([^0-9]|$)/\1$newIP\2/g" input
```

OR on Mac:

```
sed -E "s/(^|[^:])$oldIP([^0-9]|$)/\1$newIP\2/g" input
```

Comment: What does this command do? I am on Linux, First one is not working. command cant execute. its error.

Comment: `What does this command do?` This is a replacement of your attempt `sed -i 's/'$oldIP'/'$newIP'/g' filename`

Comment: I guess that you wouldn't need to escape `.` in the replacement variable.

Comment: @devnull: Right, escaping not needed in replacement, correcting.

Comment: @anubhava Not that it'd matter in this case :)

Comment: @devnull: True it wouldn't change the behavior but I just don't want to give wrong information to future visitors so better to correct it.

Comment: @anubhava: That is what prompted me to comment in the first place.  Good job of salvaging the question. +1